# AWS Redshift Serverless full executed queries

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

We are trying to use redshift serverless. It shows the query history is stored in the table [sys_query_history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SYS_QUERY_HISTORY.html).
But looking at the table, the `query_text` field has a 4000 characters limit. They'd truncate the query. Is there another way to get the full executed queries in Redshift Serverless?